# почему теряется 1 значение при выводе массива?

Tags: php

Есть бд(MSSQL) структура такая /имя/дата/статус/, я при помощи php подключаюсь и получаю из нее данные

```
function fetchFromSql() {
        $serverName = $this->serverName;
        $dataBase = $this->dataBase;
        $userName = $this->userName;
        $password = $this->password;

        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => $dataBase, "UID" => $userName, "PWD" => $password);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($conn === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT [name],[date],[status],row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rownum
  FROM [script_monitoring].[dbo].[script_status]) [script_status] where rownum <= 10";

        $params = array();
        $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlQuery, $params, $options);

        if (sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        return array($stmt, $conn);
    }
```

далече, я обрабатываю эти данные и освобождаю подключение

```
function convertFromSql() {
        $const = new ConnectionData();
        $handler = new DataHandler($const::SERVERNAME, $const::DATABASE, $const::USER, $const::PASS);
        $stmt = $handler->fetchFromSql();

        $arData = array();
        $arNames = array();
        $n = 0;

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt[0], SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
            $arData[$n][0] = $row[0];
            $arData[$n][1] = date_format($row[1], "Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $arData[$n][2] = $row[2];
            $arNames[$n] = $row[0];
            $n++;
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt[0]);
        sqlsrv_close($stmt[1]);

        $arUniqueNames = array_unique($arNames);

        return array($arData, $arUniqueNames);
    }
```

вот тут то и закралась ошибка - выводится первых 9 записей вместо 10 по первому имени(как бы вы можете смотреть даже не на весь код, а на цикл записи в массив), но не могу понять почему. Из базы приходят записи: для каждого уникального имени по 10 записей(это вы можете понять из запроса), если что-то непонятно напишите или же посмотрите полностью здесь (https://github.com/Vankalif/script_mon)

Так же обнаружено что при моем запросе в MSSQL я получаю вот такой ответ:

```
name    date    status  rownum
Awayalogs   2017-02-28 23:59:19.327 1   1
Awayalogs   2017-02-27 23:59:14.423 1   2
Awayalogs   2017-02-21 23:59:15.490 1   3
Awayalogs   2017-02-20 23:59:16.350 1   4
Awayalogs   2017-02-19 23:59:12.927 1   5
Awayalogs   2017-02-18 23:59:17.993 1   6
Awayalogs   2017-02-17 23:59:12.600 1   7
Awayalogs   2017-02-16 23:59:20.817 1   8
Awayalogs   2017-02-15 23:59:13.690 1   9
Awayalogs   2017-02-14 23:59:14.040 1   10
```

однако при дебаге проекта я вижу, что вот здесь `$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt[0], SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)`
уже стоит почему-то вторая строка `Awayalogs    2017-02-27 23:59:14.423 1   2`, а не первая. Что за мистика, помогите разобраться!

Comment: Если вы используете `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rownum` только для ограничения количества выводимых записей, куда эффективнее было бы использовать `LIMIT 10` вместо этого. Возможно, тогда и проблема пропадет.

Comment: Это не возможно, SQL 2008

Comment: Проблема не в запросе, до рефакторинга, всех записей было по 10

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 [name],[date],[status] FROM [script_monitoring].[dbo].[script_status]`

Comment: Еще раз, запрос выводит все как надо по 10 записей по каждому имени

Comment: Мало того TOP 10 выведет 10 последних записей.

Comment: Именно по этой причине его назвали TOP - чтобы не путаться )

Comment: @Aleksei вы пишите про 10 записей всего, а запрос автора выводит первые 10 для каждого пользователя. Это разные запросы.

Comment: Автор, у вас в `fetchFromSql` есть строка `sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)` она вам случаем не пропускает  первый результат?

Comment: вообще беда, конечно, с архитектурой так сказать.

Comment: Это слабо сказано), я переделываю его вот и столкнулся с проблемами.

Comment: читайте выше мой коммент про `fetch` ваша проблема в этом.

Comment: teran, расскажи как ты это понял и почему оно резало только одну строчку, действительно проблема в этом!

Comment: потому что `fetch*` читает строку и датасета. вы же в цикле читаете набор с помощью fetch по одной записи. Раз одна (первая) не выводилась, значит читалась где то ранее. Вот собственно мы и нашли ее.

Comment: Крутяк, спасибо!